# JavaFX: Loosing stylesheet's effect after scene.setRoot()

Tags: java, css, javafx, scene, stage

I have to switch between 2 pages.
To provide such a feature I use the scene.setRoot(myNewPane); method to switch to the new page.
My scene has a stylesheet, added in this way:

```
scene.getStyleSheets().add(myCssUrl.toExternalForm());
```

when I switch to the new page all the stylesheet effects are lost (fonts, text color, background color turn back to default values).
The problem persists even if I call again

```
scene.getStyleSheets().add(myCssUrl.toExternalForm());
```

or if I create a new Scene and add the stylesheet.

If I define a global stylesheet:

```
 Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(StyleValues.CSS_URL.toExternalForm());
```

the effects I see are not the ones expected.

In few words: I can't switch between two pages wich are decorated with stylesheets.

What I need is a way to do it.

Comment: Maybe you have custom css selectors which are used in first page but not in 2nd page?